# Publishing to RackspaceCloud Cloud Sites from Visual studio - files get skipped

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, rackspace-cloud

My team has been publishing asp.net web applications (MVC 3 and 4) directly to RackspaceCloud Cloud Sites for over a year now. We've experienced that some files often (apparently) get skipped over and not published to the Cloud Site when using Visual Studio's Build > Publish Selection functionality. Even though the file has changed in my project, the changed file doesn't get published to the ftp. When we realize that this has happened, we end up manually connecting to the ftp with a normal ftp client, and manually uploading the changed files by hand.

Has anyone else experienced this problem when publishing asp.net applications to rackspace cloud sites using visual studio? And is there a solution?

Some other things to note:

- I've spoken with RackspaceCloud support and they claim they've never heard of such a problem.
- I've experienced this using both Visual Studio 2010 and 2012.
- I've NEVER experienced this problem using any other type of hosting, only RackspaceCloud Cloud Sites.

Answer (score 2):

One thing to check: http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/how-to-rebuild-an-aspnet-application-in-cloud-sites documents the rebuild step. Without performing this step it *looks* like your site didn't update, although the FTP files are there. The reason is that an overwrite to the web.config does *not* force the web servers to re-read from the FTPed files! (In addition to the documented methods, I find renaming web.config to web.config.bak and then web.config also works.)

If your FTP files are actually not updating it is most likely a permission error: I found that the two users who were updating were conflicting because of insufficient group level permissions (i.e., read write to owner, but only read to group). Using a different FTP client turned out to "fix" things because we uploaded using the site admin account, which has more permissions.

Comment: what is your deployment process like? It sounds like you must do a publish to file system locally from VS, and then upload ALL of those files over top of the target site via FTP using the master site admin account?

Comment: I have used both the built in VS Publish (via FTP) and publishing to a staging area and uploading the result. Either way I have to refresh the web.config via one of the techniques mentioned (overwrites just aren't noticed). The publish does happen using the client's "master" account though... previously we set up less powerful FTP users, but that was when we encountered the FTP permission problem when using VS's Publish. Once we used the master account that part of the problem went away as well.